# different component for each angular material stepper step via *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can't figure out how loop through a list of steps for the stepper and use a different component for each one using `*ngFor`.

I'm currently doing this:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper
  [linear]="true"
  [labelPosition]="labelPosition"
  (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
  [selectedIndex]="currentStep"
  #stepper>

  <mat-step [completed]="steps[0].completed" [label]="steps[0].label">
    <app-my-component-0 [someInput0]="someInput0" (someOutput0)="onSomeOutput0($event)" *ngIf="currentStep === 0"></app-my-component-0>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [completed]="steps[1].completed" [label]="steps[1].label">
    <app-my-component-1 [someInput1]="someInput1" (someOutput1)="onSomeOutput1($event)" *ngIf="currentStep === 1"></app-my-component-1>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [completed]="steps[2].completed" [label]="steps[2].label">
    <app-my-component-2 [someInput2]="someInput2" (someOutput2)="onSomeOutput2($event)" *ngIf="currentStep === 2"></app-my-component-2>
  </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Is there a more elegant way? I think I need to do something with `ngTemplate` but I'm not familiar enough to get it working.

Comment: So basically you want to have different component in each step, correct? if so why you want to use `*ngFor`?

Comment: Yes. Because I would like to also make the `steps` generic. I would like to have list of steps, which includes their components, and be able to create different steppers.

Comment: Check if it helps: https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it with `*ngFor` and `ngSwitch` as follows:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper ...>
  <mat-step *ngFor=let step of [0,1,2]" [ngSwitch]="step" [completed]="steps[step].completed" [label]="steps[step].label">
    <app-my-component-0 *ngSwitchCase="0" [someInput0]="someInput0" (someOutput0)="onSomeOutput0($event)"></app-my-component-0>
    <app-my-component-1 *ngSwitchCase="1" [someInput1]="someInput1" (someOutput1)="onSomeOutput1($event)"></app-my-component-1>
    <app-my-component-2 *ngSwitchCase="2" [someInput2]="someInput2" (someOutput2)="onSomeOutput2($event)"></app-my-component-2>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxmmdv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a simplified example.

Comment: Hi, can I ask for a working stackblitz example. I'm new and unable understand *ngSwitchCase="0" [someInput0]="someInput0" (someOutput0)="onSomeOutput0($event). In my case, the values are dynamic and not 0,1, 2 etc